# PGN input field and software to depict this input as board position

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we implement a replayer for chess analysis on the site?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site)

We need to somehow plan to get a separate input field to accept PGN board position as well as some software to translate this into showing the board position.
Additonally we can have the PGN notation to see the moves for the game under question.
Any suggestions on how to get this done?

Comment: Similarly, the ability to generate a board image from a [FEN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) string would be nice.

Comment: I agree.  We're talking about chess, and a way to use the chess language (diagrams and notation) easily would be helpful.

Comment: Um, I volunteer to implement it, if the SO guys will let me.

Comment: Any ideas on how to take this forward? Should we contact Jeff or Sam Saffron?

Answer (score 10):

I think we badly need this feature, a PGN tag which will convert notation to an actual playable board would be awesome too, most chess websites have some kind of mechanism to do that

Comment: I agree an interactive board like the one found on chess.com would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

As well as making the usage of the site easier, having such a tool would mean that all the diagrams on the site could look consistent rather than having each questioner use their own preferred tool to generate an image.

Not only are user-generated images not searchable (e.g. if you wanted to find all board positions that involved a certain pattern) they will end up looking inconsistent over time.

Answer (score 0):

Support for ubiquitous [FEN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) tags (which is more important imho) should probably be added as a start. The pgn viewer etc can come later.