# Could we implement a chess diagram/sequence tool?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PGN input field and software to depict this input as board position](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/pgn-input-field-and-software-to-depict-this-input-as-board-position)

I don't know how hard it would be, but is it possible to allow people to post chess diagrams using only the Chess.SE posting tools?  The alternative we've been using is to use an online tool, and then uploading a screenshot or online image.

It would be best if we could use manual setup and FEN game notation for diagrams, and PGN as well for sequences.

Is this possible, and if so, could it be implemented?

Comment: asked before http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15/pgn-input-field-and-software-to-depict-this-input-as-board-position