# how about having a way to add and show a board in the questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PGN input field and software to depict this input as board position](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/pgn-input-field-and-software-to-depict-this-input-as-board-position)

There are a times when one tries to ask about best move at a point in the game. And I think it would be best to have a way to attach a board to a question. how about it?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, see [here](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15/pgn-input-field-and-software-to-depict-this-input-as-board-position) and [here](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/3/javascript-plugins). We certainly do need this feature.

Comment: ohhh! they didn't turn up in my related questions