# Chess Beta: Proposed Move Generator

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we implement a replayer for chess analysis on the site?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site)

I was just at the chess stackexchange and saw this post:

[Very Aggressive Openings](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/75/very-aggressive-openings)

The GIF of the chess moves would make understanding the moves much easier by visualization.

A board could be setup with a FEN: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth-Edwards_Notation

and then use the notation they use now to animate the moves such as `1.e4 e5 2.d4 exd4 3.c3 dxc3 4.Bc4 cxb2 5.Bxb2` could be applied to animate it.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful, but why not just use one of the myriad chess moves gif generator? For example: http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php

Comment: Didn't know each SE had it's own meta. Can someone please move this over to chess meta? @Yannis, that's a good one - the idea was to bring something like that to make it easier on the SE so that most answers start using it. I guess why reinvent the wheel, besides making it a tad easier and perhaps bringing uniformity

Comment: @BHare Flag the question for moderation attention and ask for it to be moved to Meta Chess. Even if it's closed, don't worry about it, it can be re-opened and migrated when a moderator sees your flag.

Comment: Displaying FEN is more important than having a GIF, which I find distracting without a means of controlling it.

Answer (score 1):

The related idea of a tool that would allow PGN input to display a game board was brought up [a while back](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/167) here on meta. Incorporating the ability to input positions via FEN was mentioned in comments there as well. This would indeed be a very useful tool to have on the site. It would greatly streamline the inclusion of diagrams, and would greatly improve the inclusion of analysis/variations in posts. And the added uniformity and aesthetic appeal might help make the site more immediately attractive to new users too.

I don't know what the best way to go about implementing such a tool would be. One idea - I don't know how feasible this would be - is to incorporate use of the [Chess Tempo PGN viewer](http://chesstempo.com/pgn-usage.html) on the site. I know that viewer is used by sites such as ChessVibes (see it in action in [this post](http://www.chessvibes.com/reports/kravtsiv-tiviakov-win-first-lbv-tournament), for instance). Anyway, like I said, I don't know what the best way to do this would be, but you're right that it would be a fantastic addition to the site.