# How to add comments/annotations in the replayer?

Tags: discussion, pgn-viewer

I am unable to figure out how to add a comment in a replayer, but in here it is said it can be done. 
[Can we get inline comments implemented in the PGN viewer? [Done!]](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/can-we-get-inline-comments-implemented-in-the-pgn-viewer-done)

Can you please tell me how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add comments, place them inside braces `{` and `}` at the point in the move list you want them to appear. For example:

```
[fen ""]

1.e4 c5 {Sicilian Defense} 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 e5 {Kalashnikov variation}
```

in a post on the main site will produce a PGN viewer with the first few moves of the Kalashnikov Sicilian along with the indicated comments.

Comment: thanks broda :)