# How to include diagrams in posts on stack exchange

Tags: discussion

Where is this documented? I have been including FENs which have mostly turned into diagrams, but I suspect someone may be helping.

Comment: See balpha's answer to [this earlier meta post](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/3/167).

Comment: The link in @ETD's comment above doesn't work for me (I get an SSL version mismatch error using latest supported version of Chrome on Windows 8.1 -- I know, I should upgrade, but this is an old laptop...), but rearranging the parts of the domain name to [this](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site) does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I give an example of how to do it then you will just see the diagram!

The best way is for you to edit a post which has such a diagram so that you can see exactly how it is done. Copy the part that is displaying the diagram, paste it into your text editor, change it with the data for your game and then try posting it. Of course you should just cancel out of the edit of the original post.

That's how I did it the first time and even now if I want to include a diagram I edit one of my old posts to copy and paste a working example.

Comment: You could have included it here so people don't have to search through all the questions to find one holding diagram - it would be possible then to open edit here and see how it looks - in this format answer is not useful