# What PGN-viewer is used here?

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

What PGN-Viewer is used on this site? Is it open source? Freeware? I am looking for something on my chess club web site. I searched here about the PGN-Viewer but could not find the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PGN viewer used on Chess SE comes from [here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site/169#169), and is licensed under the MIT license (very permissive).