# Castling notation in replayer

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

I was using the [chess replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/175/10887) earlier and couldn't get it to castle. It turns out that I was typing 0-0 and the replayer only recognises O-O.

I couldn't find anywhere on the chess meta explaining which notation to use for castling and both forms are viable to notate a castling move.

Would it be worth making a small change so that we can use both O and 0 in the replayer?

Answer (score 2):

There was a [pull request](https://github.com/andrewphoy/chess-replayer/pull/7) for this on GitHub, but it was not accepted based on the reasoning that O-O is the common and “correct” notation.