# Uploading .pgn files to chess.SE

Tags: feature-request

I have a .pgn file I would like to upload, but I don't see an option for that.

Another option is to convert it to a .txt file and upload it, but could the above be implemented for mobile users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we implement a replayer for chess analysis on the site?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site)

Comment: @Andrew T. Nop. First of all we tried that (see my last question). Second of all we can't upload .pgns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PGN *is* a text file. You can just open it in any text file viewer and copy the content to the site.

A practical problem is that uploads are currently only possible for images: they go to imgur.com, which allows image files only.